# Where to delete model image?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model with an image field and I want to be able to change the image using a ModelForm. When changing the image, the old image should be deleted and replaced by the new image.

I have tried to do this in the clean method of the ModelForm like this:

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ModelForm, self).clean()

        old_profile_image = self.instance.image
        if old_profile_image:
            old_profile_image.delete(save=False)        
        return cleaned_data
```

This works fine unless the file indicated by the user is not correct (for example if its not an image), which result in the image being deleted without any new images being saved. I would like to know where is the best place to delete the old image? By this I mean where can I be sure that the new image is correct before deleting the old one?

Edit:
I prefer to do this in my ModelForm class if possible.

Comment: I'm confused by your questions.  Some are not questions (like the first sentence after the code).  Others, like the question about "best" are opinions or deeply associated with your design.  I'd like to help -- can you edit your question some to be clearer?

Comment: I have edited it a bit. I hope its more clear now. If not let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to do it in a clean way using a ModelForm. Basically I create a class called 'ChangeImageForm', which will make sure to delete the old image when changing an image. Furthermore it also works if an image is invalid:

```
class ChangeImageForm(ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ModelForm, self).clean()
        self.old_image = self.instance.image
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(ChangeImageForm, self).save(commit)

        if self.old_image:
            self.old_image.delete(save=False)

        return instance
```

Now I can easily add the above functionality to a ModelForm with an image field by inheriting from ChangeImageForm like this:

```
class MyModelForm(ChangeImageForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel # model with an image field
```

I think overriding the ModelForm is the best place to do this, instead of in the Model class, since I only want to delete the old image in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers:

An ImageField should validate that the uploaded file is an image via the Python Imaging Library.  If it is not, the form will not validate.

Your ImageField should have a path to the old file in its path attribute.

You can delete the old image after you save the new one.  Better, don't ever use the user's filename input as a filename.  That's safer, and you can just use the same filename -- then you just overwrite the old file each time and can drop the delete step.

Good luck.